# Tuning SQL query for Ignite Cache

Tags: ignite

I have enabled SQL support for my cache and i am running below query on a large dataset.
I keep on getting warning messages -

WARNING: **Query execution is too long** [duration=3625ms, type=MAP, distributedJoin=false, enforceJoinOrder=false, lazy=false,
LIMIT 200, node=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=e70cc42c-fae6-420d-87f1-8102e386b27a, consistentId=10.105.143.70, addrs=ArrayList [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, 10.105.143.70, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=HashSet [/10.105.143.70:47500, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:47500, /127.0.0.1:47500], discPort=47500, order=1, intOrder=1, lastExchangeTime=1638195967523, loc=true, ver=2.10.0#20210310-sha1:bc24f6ba, isClient=false], reqId=3, segment=0]

Below is my query -

```
try (QueryCursor<List<?>> cur = cache2.query(new SqlFieldsQuery("select _key from table"))) {
    for (List<?> r : cur) {
        Long key = (Long)r.get(0);
    }
}
```

Sometimes it is taking as long as 50 seconds to fetch as low as 200 records (LIMIT 200)

Is there any way i can tune this to get the query finish quickly?

Comment: have you limit your query?

Comment: do you need all the rows from you databse?

Comment: Yes i did add limit to the query, i tried with various limit configurations - LIMIT 50, LIMIT 200. I don't get **query is running for too long** warning messages anymore but i when i see the log i can see that time taken is sometimes upto 30 seconds.

Comment: Yes i need all the records but in batches, i dont need them all together at one time.

Comment: you can try LIMIT XXX OFFSET YYY to get what you want. It will not give you warning and use hit and trial method to set both values so they take appropriate time you want.

Comment: @Rohan19 what's your goal here? Could you describe what are you doing next, once you get the complete sets of the table's keys? I think you might need an alternative API instead of SQL, but it depends on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting lazy mode on your SqlFieldsQuery:

```
try (QueryCursor<List<?>> cur = cache2.query(new SqlFieldsQuery("select _key from table").setLazy(true))) {
for (List<?> r : cur) {
    Long key = (Long)r.get(0);
}
```

}